# empty project created on android

Tags: android, main-activity

i have a problem when i create a new project android i got an empty project without mainAcivity ,Even if i try this solution : (Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) it doesn't work i got the error:  ""Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)""""
Can you help me please??

Comment: First update your SDK components by using the SDK Manager.

Comment: Second, don't use eclipse - http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html.

Comment: 1. Update SDK from SDK manager
2. Update ADT Plugin